# xamarin.forms know memory usage both for android and ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to develop android and iOS application using xamarin.forms. And already completed the main part that includes `Canvas` drawing. For that, I have used `Skiasharp`, to perform operations on bitmap images.

Now, in android,
1. If I try to dispose bitmaps that I initialized before I get `SIGSEGV` fatal error. (I think this issue is not OS specific)
2. When I continuously run my app for 20-22 minutes, app crashes suddenly.

And in iOS,
my iphone gets hanged when I run my app for long time. And it doesn't start until I uninstall app from iFunBox in my pc.

I wanted to ask if there are ways in xamarin.forms or in native projects to find out where my memory is leaking.
How can I know how much memory of RAM is actually being used at the moment ?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.xamarin.com/profiler

Comment: Thanks @Jason for the comment. but I have VS Community version. and I think profiler works on Enterprise version. I have already read about that. Will it work for xamarin studio ?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/profiler/#Profiler_Support

Answer (score 1):

For Android, you can use the Android Debug Monitor tool. This is a tool that is installed as part of the Android SDK.

Below is the URL for more information:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/798462/Diagnosing-Memory-Usage-in-a-Xamarin-Android-Appli

For iOS, you can try to use the native XCode Instrument.

Below is the URL for more information:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/using_instruments_to_detect_native_leaks_using_markheap/

Also, Below is a useful article that talk about Xamarin.Forms Memory management.
Hopefully it will be helpful.

https://igorelikblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/08/xamarin-form-memory-management/

Comment: Sorry for lil late @Janson. I tried link for ios. Is it for xamarin.ios specific ? Because, I tried for my pcl code but I couldn't see any code responsible for memory leaks as shown in documentation.

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086015/5483868) helps me to found the memory leak that cause in my Android device.